# csv data streaming using Kafka

Tags: csv, apache-kafka

I am trying to send csv file data throguh producer into kafka topic then on the consumer side i am listening the event.

Producer is a command line. I am sending the csv file using below command -

```
kafka-console-producer.bat --broker-list localhost:9092 --topic freshTopic < E:\csv\sample.csv
```

I am sucessfully listen the event on consumer side as well.

Now I have to save that data in some database like elasticsearch. For this i have to convert csv records into DataModel. I read below tutorial for it but not able to understand that how can i write this in java. So Can anyone help me here how can i convert csv file data into datamodel? Thanks in advance.

[Csv data streaming using kafka](https://medium.com/@eswar.kumar/csv-data-streaming-using-kafka-schema-registry-and-avro-920a1de63016)

Comment: Hope this may help, here is relatively new project for streaming CSV files into Kafka : https://github.com/streamthoughts/kafka-connect-file-pulse

Answer (score 1):

What you wrote will work fine to get data into Kafka. There are lots of ways to get data into Elasticsearch (which is not a database) from there...

You don't need Avro, as JSON will work too, but [confluent-schema-registry](/questions/tagged/confluent-schema-registry) doesn't handle conversion from CSV, and Kafka has no "DataModel" class.

Assuming you **want** Avro to get it into Elasticsearch as individual fields, then

1. You could use [Kafka Connect spooldir source **instead**](https://github.com/jcustenborder/kafka-connect-spooldir) of the console producer, and that would get you further along, and then you can run Elasticsearch sink connector from there
2. Use *something* to parse the CSV to Avro, as the link you have shows (doesn't have to be Python, KSQL could work too)

If you are fine with JSON, then Logstash would work as well

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Now i read csv file and converted into a datamodel using "com.opencsv" and transfering that datamodel over kafka using custom serializer. but now i a getting again an exception- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55534215/exception-in-spring-kafka-deserialization     Please have a look and suggest me any solution for it. Thanks